# Do large varieties grown in a pot yield small fruits or die?

Tags: containers, variety-selection, pumpkins, sunflowers

Consider those large varieties of pumpkins or sunflowers eg mammoth sunflower. What would happen if one plants such a large variety in a small container ?
Would the plant restrict it's growth and yield small fruits, like a smaller variety would ?
Or would it just die after reaching the spacial limits ?

Comment: Sunflowers will likely be stunted, and any fruiting plant, while also being stunted, may not produce useful fruit. Can't you at least use very large pots?

Comment: Sunflowers will have smaller flowers, but still grow.